# Inkscape: order of drag-and-dropped images

Tags: inkscape

1. Win10, I'm selecting a bunch of images in Explorer.
2. I drag-N-drop them into inkscape. The images are imported one on top of the other.
3. I'm selecting all of them using a simple square selection (or ctrl+a).
4. Align and distribute> remove overlaps. The images are sorted in a row, but their order is random.

How do I sort them alphabetically (according to the source image file names)?

I tried to change the file timestamps to follow alphabetical order, but inkscape still sorted them randomly.

Comment: Could you include some screenshots?

Comment: Which step isn't clear?

Comment: Say I have 1.png, 2.png, 3.png. I follow my steps. I'd like a row, where 1.png is on the left and 3.png is on the right.

Comment: There is no such feature in Inkscape. Maybe you may need to write your own extension.

Comment: Any idea what's the default order based on? It would probably be easier to just generate a latex file, compile a pdf, and import it to inkscape.

Comment: Write a script which orders the filenames by name. Then for each file evaluate it's width (for example with ImageMagick: identify), generate a core SVG-file yourself with the images in right order. As Linux user I don't know, how to invoke a script for a bunch of marked files in the browser, but in essence it could be a *.bat-file, which receives its arguments as parameters.

Comment: Latex is easier.